# How to get terminal size in Spyder?

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, size, spyder, shutil

I am trying to get the terminal size using the function `shutil.get_terminal_size()`.
This works well in a Python console or an Ipython console, but not in the Ipython console inside the Spyder editor, and I don't understand why.

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Spyder consoles are not "real" consoles, i.e. they are not based on the same technologies as those used in terminal-based consoles (such as `cmd.exe` or `Terminal.app`). Therefore, `shutil.get_terminal_size()` doesn't work as expected.

Actually, our console's width is fixed at 80 characters and right now (October 2020) that limit can't be changed.